# Algorithm for searching two numbers whose absolute difference is small

Tags: algorithms

Let $A$ be an array of numbers. Let $y$ be positive.

We want to find two numbers $A[i]$ and $A[j]$ such that their absolute difference is at most $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a hash *set* (← that refers to the question text before they vandalized it, just like the names $x_i$ instead of $A[i]$), use a hash *map*. Store each $x_i$ under its hash $h_i = \lfloor \frac{x_i}{y} \rfloor$. But before you store it, check it against the hash entries $h_i-1$, $h_i$ and $h_i+1$ and report a pair if it's close enough.

Python implementation:

```
def pair(xs, y):
    seen = {}
    for x in xs:
        h = x // y
        for H in h-1, h, h+1:
            if H in seen:
                X = seen[H]
                if abs(x - X) <= y:
                    return X, x
        seen[h] = x

print(pair([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 3.14], 1.1))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BCoMwEETvfsUcla7aVClS6t1PEMSDpUq8xBAtREq/3WYVLMVhL5s3M2z0PMlBJZk2y/JsO@imN74dCXNw8@A0tq1Cjvdn3brBwKJXsOOGWdJxizjGvD@xr2CfDAVBujmJX4DVd5uB@/8Jq3SVTKqiPjCXbB6jbxGiDHDPMR/zLNNOL6NQEuzO105Z88Gep02vJn/9cXUmXAgp4UrICEkk0pogIhEEy/IF)):

```
(4, 3.14)
```

Comment: (I think you don't need to check `x - X` where `h in seen`.)

Comment: @greybeard Yes, and for the other two I could avoid the `abs`. But I wanted to keep the explanation and code simple (as in avoid code duplication).